# Cloudinary Upload widget in android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, cloudinary, image-upload

I am using the upload widget for image upload in android. despite using the " **`UploadWidget.Options(UploadWidget.Action.NONE`**" as required in the docs, the onActivityResult function in not triggered. The image is uploaded immediately so I can't intercept the upload.